# Why does this generic cast fail

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code:

```
kAIDataPort<T> lOtherEndCast = ( kAIDataPort<T>)lOtherEnd;
```

Which raises the following exception:

```
[A]kAI.Core.kAIDataPort`1[UnityEngine.GameObject] cannot be cast to 
[B]kAI.Core.kAIDataPort`1[UnityEngine.GameObject]. Type A originates from 'kAICore...
```

(Exception shrunk for readability, but there is no difference between A and B.

All the other questions on generic casting seem to relate to lists and inherited types, but here we just have an object of a certain type and not being able to cast it to precisely that type.

Not looking for a work around, I am using a non-generic base class with a non-typed method to do what I need to do, I just want to understand why this raises an exception.

This is in .NET 3.5 (since using Unity which still doesn't support .NET 4...)

Full exception:

```
[A]kAI.Core.kAIDataPort`1[UnityEngine.GameObject] cannot be cast to 
[B]kAI.Core.kAIDataPort`1[UnityEngine.GameObject]. 
Type A originates from 'kAICore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'E:\dev\C#\kAI\kAI-Editor\bin\Debug\kAICore.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'kAICore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'E:\dev\C#\kAI\kAI-Editor\bin\Debug\kAICore.dll'.
```

**Update:**

The problem was loading the Unity DLL twice, but it was loading the same DLL (but never unloading). The code for this is:

```
FileStream lDLLStream = lDllPath.GetFile().OpenRead();
byte[] lDLLArray = new byte[lDLLStream.Length];
lDLLStream.Read(lDLLArray, 0, (int)lDLLStream.Length);
lDLLStream.Close();
Assembly lLoadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(lDLLArray);

// Force the loading of the dll
lLoadedAssembly.GetExportedTypes();

return lLoadedAssembly;
```

The path was the same both times, so why would the case get confused about which dll to load from?

Further, loading the DLL twice this way and examining the following things just before the exception I get:

```
this.GetType().Equals(lOtherEnd.GetType())  false
```

but on the generic argument:

```
typeof(T).Equals(lOtherEnd.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0])   true
```

Comment: Can you expand the exception message? It actually tells why the cast failed. It looks like you're having multiple assemblies defining the same type.

Comment: Have included the full exception, but I truncated since they do come from the same assembly as can be seen (unless I am going blind here!)

Comment: Ridiculous, Can you post some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: is it the difference between the unbounded and constructed generic types (ie the compile time cast on the unbound rather than run time type).  If you performed kAIDataPort<T> lOtherEndCast = lOtherEnd as lOtherEndkAIDataPort<T>; does that work?

Comment: @AlexC no, using `as` returns null (though no exception obviously...)

Comment: @AK_ not really sure what that means... however, have created a simple example and the exception doesn't happen so it must be something to do with conflicting dlls being loaded

Comment: My honest suggestion: 1. make sure have the latest version of the framework 3.5 sp1 (?) 2. make sure your visual studio is updated. 3. try reopening VS, try restarting the computer. 4. delete all the DLLs\OBJs\EXEs, and rebuild. 5. try re-adding all the references making sure they are correct.

Comment: I think it may be to do with the `GameObject`, the generic parameter, which comes from a DLL I am loading dynamically at run time (was totally not focusing on that part of the error, assumed it was just because generic) and finding that for some reason I load it twice but don't unload in between. Investigating that at the moment...

Comment: 6. Windows updates... 7. make sure you close the hosting process VS uses for debiging, and VS itself

Comment: @T.Kiley as long as it's the exact same assembly, you should be ok...

Comment: Extend Sriram's advice to the GameObject: if you load the assembly with GamObj twice, make sure that those 2 assemblies are THE same assembly, with the same StrongName, with the same CodeBase/Location etc. It might have happened that you have 2 similar but not identical gameobject assemlies loaded, hence `port<>` class is the same, but that's actually `port<T1>` and `port<T2>` and the T1!=T2 despite having the same name.

Comment: Fixing the double load stopped the exception... definitely loading the same DLL from same place though, as executing the same line twice. I'll update the question to include load code

Comment: If you somehow forced the runtime to load the same assembly TWICE, then this will be loaded TWICE as TWO assemblies - identical in binary image, but different handles. You can get it ie. by loading the same assembly in different AppDomains. Type from LEFT AppDomain will be different than the same type from the same assembly from the RIGHT AppDomain. And so on. For the case to be valid, the Types/Assemblies must be EXACTLY the same. Object.ReferenceEquals-same. Rewind the code, invoke the bug again and check left.GetType()==right.GetType(). I bet they're `false`.

Comment: See see my edit. Stop loading "from bytes" if possible.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Per your suggestion, I tried checking if the two types were equal. Naturally, for the `kAIDataPort<GameObject>`, they did not match, but doing on the individual generic parameter, they did. This I don't understand, surely they weren't matching on precisely the generic parameter. This feels kinda tangential, maybe I should do another question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a generic type - the cast checks four types: `T1<T2>` versus `T3<T4>`.

So, the collision can be either `T1<G>` vs `T2<G>` OR it can be `T<G1>` vs `T<G2>`.

The debug messages only printed information about 'T' and indeed it seems the same. So, check the Gs.

EDIT:

<strike>Now I would not guess you'd do that. You were precisely generating multiple images of the same assembly. All types created from them would always be different.</strike>

An assembly that is loaded FROM BYTES is never 'equal' to any other assembly. It is always loaded with new handle and never "coerced/collapsed" with any already loaded assembly. It is always described as having `null` codebase/location and treated similarily to "dynamic assemblies", created on-the-fly. ( I tried to find a reference for that and I cannot. I'm still quite sure about it, but I'm striking it just to warn you that it may not be true. Here's a starter for reading about assembly loading contexts: [What are 3 kinds of Binding Contexts for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493786/what-are-3-kinds-of-binding-contexts-for) )

Why do you load it from raw bytes? Load it from FILE/PATH. Then it will get its codebase/location set properly and multiple loads will results in only one handle in memory.

Comment: -> [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It works perfectly, I can load the DLL multiple times (though having found that, clearly don't need that any more :P) and it still performs the cast, thanks.

Comment: Great! I'm still curious why the outer `T<G>` were different while the inner Gs were same.. are you sure that objects created from two assemblies loaded from identical byte-arrays had precisely the same `GetType()` class object? I thought that if the assembly gets loaded twice, it generates different Type objects of the same names/namespaces :/

Comment: Ok, I saw your edit. Thanks! I'll need to check it myself, because I **remember** that there were some case.. ah, nevermind ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're casting a type `T1` from assembly `A1` to `T1` in assembly `A2`. Indeed both are not same. So it fails.