# Finding base type of types loaded from reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a basic scenario.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
Type[] temp = asm.GetTypes();
bool matchFound = false;
foreach (Type t in temp)
{
    if (t.IsClass && t.IsSubClassOf(typeof(MyBaseClass)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match found");
        matchFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

In this case no match found. But if I add reference of that assembly and call this method again.

```
bool matchFound = typeof(MyDerivedClass).IsSubClassOf(typeof(MyBaseClass));
```

matchFound is true in this case.

I want first case to be running. Any suggestion

Comment: Are your base type and derived type both defined in the assembly you are loading/referencing?

Comment: Base type is in different assembly asmb1, derived type is defined asmb2 and I am calling from asmb3. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies loaded via `LoadFrom` are not loaded into the default assembly context. This can cause problems like yours. Try using `Assemlby.Load` instead.
Here are a few links for more info´s that could be usefull

http://gotoanswer.com/?q=Loading+a+class+from+an+assembly+dynamically+%28C%23%29

[Reflection not working on assembly that is loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218013/reflection-not-working-on-assembly-that-is-loaded-using-assembly-loadfrom)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172214.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/rupreet/archive/2010/02/16/137988.aspx